# throw Exception in lambda(or equivalent) - javafx

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, fxml

I am trying to get a popup to come up asking the user if they wish to exit the program everytime they click the exit button (x in the the top left corner). However I am using FXML and have to throw an exception when I try to load the popup with `primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>{}` I keep getting a unhandled Exception error even when I throw the error in the method I am calling from. I have tried try and catch and while there isn't an error the code doesn't run. I am currently trying to see if I can wrap the method in another so I can maybe get around the exception however nothing has seemed to work. Is there any way to use `setOnCloseRequest` with a thrown `Exception`?

```
public class Main extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception  {
        File f = new File("Goal.txt");
        boolean bool = false;

        if (f.exists() )
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainPage.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            primaryStage.setTitle("Money Saver Program");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        else
        {
            bool = f.createNewFile();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("OpeningPage.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Money Saver Program");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 638, 400));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                event.consume();
                closeProgram();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void closeProgram(){
        try{internalCloseProgram();}catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public void internalCloseProgram()throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FinalExitMessage.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Money Saver Program");
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot throw an [**checked** exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) from a lambda expression/anonymus class, if the exception is not assignable to a exception in the `throws` clause of the abstract method of the functional interface.

What could be done is throwing a new unchecked exception that has the exception as it's cause:

```
try{
    internalCloseProgram();
} catch (Exception e){
     throw new IllegalStateException("something went wrong", e);
}
```

However nothing happening seems to be an indication that loading the `FinalExitMessage.fxml` failed. Note: simply "swallowing" an exception is not a good idea, unless you know for sure it can be safely ignored and you don't need the information for debugging.

---

Furthermore by consuming the event in the `onCloseRequest` call, you tell JavaFX to ignore the attempt to close the window. You need to close the stage yourself, in case you want to close it, using

```
primaryStage.close();
```

You could also use

```
Platform.exit();
```

from the `Stage` shown in the `internalCloseProgram` method.

Also you could wait for the user to interact with the new stage by calling `showAndWait` instead of `show` on the new stage to wait until the new stage is closed.

**Additional recommendation:** Use modality to block events to the primary stage while the new stage is shown.

---

The following example asks, if the window should be closed using an `Alert`. The `showAndWait` method of `Alert` is different from `Stage.showAndWait`: It returns an `Optional<ButtonType>` returning the user pick. For a `Stage` you'd need to access the controller to get the result.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 100, 100);

    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(evt -> {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you really want to close this applicetion?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        ButtonType result = alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO);

        if (ButtonType.NO.equals(result)) {
            // no choice or no clicked -> don't close
            evt.consume();
        }
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```